# Sorting LinkedList<MyClass>

Tags: java, linked-list, comparator

How do I sort `list1` with `MyClass` type of objects using `list1.sort();` method

If I want the list to be sorted depending on Priority int value?
So MyClass object with biggest priority will be at index 0 in LinkedList list1.

`LinkedList<MyClass> list1 = new LinkedList<>();`

this is what MyClass looks like and it has no Overriden methods.

```
public class MyClass {    
    int id;
    int LeftTime;
    int Priority;
    int Rasp;

    public Dretva(int[] lista) {
        this.id = lista[1];
        this.LeftTime = lista[2];
        this.Priority = lista[3];
        this.Rasp = lista[4];
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%d/%d/%d", id, Priority ,LeftTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a custom comparator.

Comment: Implement `Comparator` for your class use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom comparator like this:

```
static class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>
 {
     public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2)
     {
         return c1.getPriority().compareTo(c2.getPriority());
     }
 }
```

And then use `Collections.sort(list1,new MyClassComparator());`